# Treating javascript files NOT as typescript transcription in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea

In many folders in my js/ts project (which is something I cannot change) I have js and ts files with same name eg. myFile.ts and myFile.js. The problem is IntelliJ interprets this js file as a ts transcription and doesn't allow for file or phrase search.

So my question is how to enable search in those js files. (As you might expect searching is working just fine in ts files, this problem is only about js)

Comment: Why don't you use WebStorm instead which has focus on Front-end web development?

Comment: As of now , I am unfortunately bound to use IntelliiJ :(